# Creating an Internal Only Service in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, internals, clamav

Im trying to create an internal service only within kubernetes. Its a clamav service, the docker container runs on port 3310. I have created a deployment and a service.

I have put the service and deployment in a 'clamav' namespace

I have port forwarded both the service and pods and can confirm it works as expected.

If I connect directly to the pod and run `curl localhost:3310` its good, if i `curl clamav` (no port as ive configured 80 as the incoming service port) (which clamav being the service name) I get the following 503 error:

```
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination
```

If I connect to a different service and try the same `curl clamav.clamav` I get the same error. (no port as ive configured 80 as the incoming service port)

Do I need something else other than a service and deployment or is something misconfigured?

The service spec is shown below.

```
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.10.255.194
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3310
  selector:
    app: clamav
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

I have tried changing the name to "3310-3310" and changing the port to "3310" as well... had to update the curl commands to have the :3310 for the port... but same error.

Also just to add, I do have the istio service mesh running in this cluster and injected.

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: I just want to add to this, that ive just kinda got it working..

Istio is injected in all of the namespaces... 
I removed istio injection from both this namespace and another namespace, and i could connect between them... added istio back in and get same error, so seems the error is to do with istio somewhere...

We do need istio though .

Comment: Can you paste information from comment to your post. Also can you provide more details (whole yaml files) - are you using specific tutorial  for setup ?

Comment: no tutorial, but without istio running in my clamav namespace, i can use the service fine, if i disable istio in another namespace, they can then communicate fine. As soon as I add istio back in (envoy proxy) the communication problems occur again.

Comment: Can you provide more details (whole yaml files- service, deployment) - environment are you working on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this was the service, changing it to:

```
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.10.255.194
  ports:
  - name: tcp-clamav
    port: 80
    targetPort: 3310
  selector:
    app: clamav
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

Fixed the issue